# Найти строки в DataFrame, отсутствующие в другом DataFrame

Tags: python, pandas, update, dataframe

Коллеги, помогите с корректным решением:
1) Имеется следующий датафрейм df_old:

```
   Policy   Creation Date   ID       Main Name   Request amout
4003563   10.12.2018    119128754   FARMLAJJN OOO    13261
4001186   10.12.2018    114523060   FRONTAJJM OOO    46414
22782601  11.12.2018    120909304   PROGRESS DSA OOO 100000
4001015   11.12.2018    108335080   AGROCENTR OOO    132052
```

2) На следующий день скачивается та же таблица и создается датафрейм df_current:

```
 Policy  Creation Date   ID     Main Name          Request amout

4003563  10.12.2018   119128754 FARMLAJJN OOO       13261
345672   11.12.2018   120909635 FIKR OOO            100000
4001015  11.12.2018   108335080 AGROCENTR OOO       132052
472366   11.12.2018   120910633 FA PORTAVENTURA OOO 75000
```

Цель: сопоставить данные и создать новый датафрейм только с теми рядами, которые не встречаются в df_old. Т.е. чтобы был df_update:

```
Policy  Creation Date   ID     Main Name        Request amout

472366   11.12.2018   120910633 FA PORTAVENTURA OOO 75000
345672   11.12.2018   120909635 FIKR OOO            100000
```

Я пытаюсь проверить по значениям столбцов Policy, Creation Date и ID вот таким образом, но результат не тот совершенно :(

```
df_update = df_current[~df_current[["Policy", "Creation Date", "ID"]].isin(df_old[["Policy", "Creation Date", "ID"]])]
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

решение:

```
In [68]: res = (cur.merge(old, indicator=True, how='outer')
                   .query("_merge == 'left_only'")
                   .drop('_merge',1))
```

результат:

```
In [69]: res
Out[69]:
   Policy Creation_Date         ID            Main_Name  Request_amout
1  345672    11.12.2018  120909635             FIKR OOO         100000
3  472366    11.12.2018  120910633  FA PORTAVENTURA OOO          75000
```

---

пошагово:

```
In [70]: cur.merge(old, indicator=True, how='outer')
Out[70]:
     Policy Creation_Date         ID            Main_Name  Request_amout      _merge
0   4003563    10.12.2018  119128754        FARMLAJJN OOO          13261        both
1    345672    11.12.2018  120909635             FIKR OOO         100000   left_only
2   4001015    11.12.2018  108335080        AGROCENTR OOO         132052        both
3    472366    11.12.2018  120910633  FA PORTAVENTURA OOO          75000   left_only
4   4001186    10.12.2018  114523060        FRONTAJJM OOO          46414  right_only
5  22782601    11.12.2018  120909304     PROGRESS DSA OOO         100000  right_only

In [71]: cur.merge(old, indicator=True, how='outer').query("_merge == 'left_only'")
Out[71]:
   Policy Creation_Date         ID            Main_Name  Request_amout     _merge
1  345672    11.12.2018  120909635             FIKR OOO         100000  left_only
3  472366    11.12.2018  120910633  FA PORTAVENTURA OOO          75000  left_only

In [72]: cur.merge(old, indicator=True, how='outer').query("_merge == 'left_only'").drop('_merge',1)
Out[72]:
   Policy Creation_Date         ID            Main_Name  Request_amout
1  345672    11.12.2018  120909635             FIKR OOO         100000
3  472366    11.12.2018  120910633  FA PORTAVENTURA OOO          75000
```